# Why are Browser Http response and Program Http response different?

Tags: java, https, tls1.2, http2, tls1.3

Trying to call `https://tls.peet.ws/api/all`

I tried http request to the uri on the browser and also tried in Java code.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .uri(new URI("https://tls.peet.ws/api/all"))
                .setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7")
                .setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                .setHeader("Accept-Language", "en")
                .setHeader("Referer", "https://tls.peet.ws/")
                .setHeader("Sec-Ch-Ua", "\"Not.A/Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"114\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"114\"")
                .setHeader("Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile", "?1")
                .setHeader("Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform", "\"Windows\"")
                .setHeader("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty")
                .setHeader("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors")
                .setHeader("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin")
                .setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36")
                .build();
        httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenAccept(s -> {
                    System.out.println(s);
                });
```

But the results are different.

What's the reason?

I need your help.

Response with code

```
{
  "ip": "198.144.149.2:59514",
  "http_version": "h2",
  "method": "GET",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
  "tls": {
    "ciphers": [
      "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO"
    ],
    "extensions": [
      {
        "name": "server_name (0)",
        "server_name": "tls.peet.ws"
      },
      {
        "name": "status_request (5)",
        "status_request": {
          "certificate_status_type": "OSCP (1)",
          "responder_id_list_length": 0,
          "request_extensions_length": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "supported_groups (10)",
        "supported_groups": [
          "X25519 (29)",
          "P-256 (23)",
          "P-384 (24)",
          "P-521 (25)",
          "X448 (30)",
          "ffdhe2048 (256)",
          "ffdhe3072 (257)",
          "ffdhe4096 (258)",
          "ffdhe6144 (259)",
          "ffdhe8192 (260)"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ec_point_formats (11)",
        "elliptic_curves_point_formats": [
          "0x00"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)",
        "protocols": [
          "h2",
          "http/1.1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "status_request_v2 (17)",
        "data": "000702000400000000"
      },
      {
        "name": "extended_master_secret (23)",
        "master_secret_data": "",
        "extended_master_secret_data": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "session_ticket (35)",
        "data": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "signature_algorithms (13)",
        "signature_algorithms": [
          "ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256",
          "ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384",
          "ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512",
          "ed25519",
          "ed25519",
          "rsa_pss_rsae_sha256",
          "rsa_pss_rsae_sha384",
          "rsa_pss_rsae_sha512",
          "rsa_pss_pss_sha256",
          "rsa_pss_pss_sha384",
          "rsa_pss_pss_sha512",
          "rsa_pkcs1_sha256",
          "rsa_pkcs1_sha384",
          "rsa_pkcs1_sha512",
          "0x402",
          "ecdsa_sha1",
          "rsa_pkcs1_sha1",
          "0x202"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "supported_versions (43)",
        "versions": [
          "TLS 1.3",
          "TLS 1.2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)",
        "PSK_Key_Exchange_Mode": "PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment (psk_dhe_ke) (1)"
      },
      {
        "name": "signature_algorithms_cert (50)",
        "data": "0024040305030603080708080804080508060809080a080b0401050106010402020302010202"
      },
      {
        "name": "key_share (51)",
        "shared_keys": [
          {
            "X25519 (29)": "a6ebae411483a28484828d94d37ee228f9acd58200f449d0d57bed82d0f9f66c"
          },
          {
            "P-256 (23)": "044e72258d8516de5ae3f5e6073685d90d0a3aa089fe41079adbd85917b054bb408a7f0108878faa03d3924c7c4154ebaa440d53a4e80690b78d07b04236ffa327"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "tls_version_record": "771",
    "tls_version_negotiated": "772",
    "ja3": "771,4866-4865-4867-49196-49195-52393-49200-52392-49199-159-52394-163-158-162-49188-49192-49187-49191-107-106-103-64-49198-49202-49197-49201-49190-49194-49189-49193-49162-49172-49161-49171-57-56-51-50-49157-49167-49156-49166-157-156-61-60-53-47-255,0-5-10-11-16-17-23-35-13-43-45-50-51,29-23-24-25-30-256-257-258-259-260,0",
    "ja3_hash": "62f6a6727fda5a1104d5b147cd82e520",
    "peetprint": "772-771|2-1.1|29-23-24-25-30-256-257-258-259-260|1027-1283-1539-2055-2056-2052-2053-2054-2057-2058-2059-1025-1281-1537-1026-515-513-514|1||4866-4865-4867-49196-49195-52393-49200-52392-49199-159-52394-163-158-162-49188-49192-49187-49191-107-106-103-64-49198-49202-49197-49201-49190-49194-49189-49193-49162-49172-49161-49171-57-56-51-50-49157-49167-49156-49166-157-156-61-60-53-47-255|0-10-11-13-16-17-23-35-43-45-5-50-51",
    "peetprint_hash": "92e116d3b813833e2bdc78ebb00bca61",
    "client_random": "be7aaeeb52b752e2911756e40387609f18acf570df14b3b09e93cf1767684bbc",
    "session_id": "65083ae8047987bda0cccefbee61e8a63d2e040b1942231cc2c8be467849ec50"
  },
  "http2": {
    "akamai_fingerprint": "1:16384,2:1,3:100,4:16777216,5:16384|33488897|0|a,m,p,s",
    "akamai_fingerprint_hash": "73fddff6c02f4da2760ec1efcca3f9a5",
    "sent_frames": [
      {
        "frame_type": "SETTINGS",
        "length": 30,
        "settings": [
          "HEADER_TABLE_SIZE = 16384",
          "ENABLE_PUSH = 1",
          "MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS = 100",
          "INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE = 16777216",
          "MAX_FRAME_SIZE = 16384"
        ]
      },
      {
        "frame_type": "WINDOW_UPDATE",
        "length": 4,
        "increment": 33488897
      },
      {
        "frame_type": "HEADERS",
        "stream_id": 1,
        "length": 478,
        "headers": [
          ":authority: tls.peet.ws",
          ":method: GET",
          ":path: /api/all",
          ":scheme: https",
          "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
          "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
          "accept-language: en",
          "authority: tls.peet.ws",
          "method: GET",
          "path: /api/all",
          "referer: https://tls.peet.ws/",
          "scheme: https",
          "sec-ch-ua: \\\"Not.A/Brand\\\";v=\\\"8\\\", \\\"Chromium\\\";v=\\\"114\\\", \\\"Google Chrome\\\";v=\\\"114\\",
          "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1",
          "sec-ch-ua-platform: \\\"Windows\\",
          "sec-fetch-dest: empty",
          "sec-fetch-mode: cors",
          "sec-fetch-site: same-origin",
          "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
        ],
        "flags": [
          "EndStream (0x1)",
          "EndHeaders (0x4)"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Browser Response

```
{
  "ip": "198.144.149.2:13072",
  "http_version": "h2",
  "method": "GET",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  "tls": {
    "ciphers": [
      "TLS_GREASE (0x2A2A)",
      "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    ],
    "extensions": [
      {
        "name": "TLS_GREASE (0xaaaa)"
      },
      {
        "name": "extensionRenegotiationInfo (boringssl) (65281)",
        "data": "00"
      },
      {
        "name": "session_ticket (35)",
        "data": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "server_name (0)",
        "server_name": "tls.peet.ws"
      },
      {
        "name": "signed_certificate_timestamp (18)"
      },
      {
        "name": "signature_algorithms (13)",
        "signature_algorithms": [
          "ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256",
          "rsa_pss_rsae_sha256",
          "rsa_pkcs1_sha256",
          "ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384",
          "rsa_pss_rsae_sha384",
          "rsa_pkcs1_sha384",
          "rsa_pss_rsae_sha512",
          "rsa_pkcs1_sha512"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)",
        "protocols": [
          "h2",
          "http/1.1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "extended_master_secret (23)",
        "master_secret_data": "",
        "extended_master_secret_data": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "supported_versions (43)",
        "versions": [
          "TLS_GREASE (0x4a4a)",
          "TLS 1.3",
          "TLS 1.2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "compress_certificate (27)",
        "algorithms": [
          "brotli (2)"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "key_share (51)",
        "shared_keys": [
          {
            "TLS_GREASE (0xcaca)": "00"
          },
          {
            "X25519 (29)": "3da35c41b2dce7ae406c0526c39c393bc9ebfd623a1ef509f36d87f53abf221f"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "application_settings (17513)",
        "protocols": [
          "h2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)",
        "PSK_Key_Exchange_Mode": "PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment (psk_dhe_ke) (1)"
      },
      {
        "name": "supported_groups (10)",
        "supported_groups": [
          "TLS_GREASE (0xcaca)",
          "X25519 (29)",
          "P-256 (23)",
          "P-384 (24)"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ec_point_formats (11)",
        "elliptic_curves_point_formats": [
          "0x00"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "status_request (5)",
        "status_request": {
          "certificate_status_type": "OSCP (1)",
          "responder_id_list_length": 0,
          "request_extensions_length": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "TLS_GREASE (0x9a9a)"
      },
      {
        "name": "padding (21)",
        "padding_data_length": 88
      },
      {
        "name": "pre_shared_key (41)",
        "data": "00770071d029b12eb298b01844996710e8e875142afee7597038c3c96961ccbc8183be7e662a48caf19ae7bb8bbb07dbd6eb763db2728e53d54cfc80d02c45cd25aaa3328b5a443e32192ae0d3b59217b6cd0f07cbd68a0e153f858a9a8daeac6a4c334eeaed2444bc879d799d514e5851df96b7db88ccea35002120d7b0ba764f658ae688d5bf71c94543bef2023a4dc0e0bc2431f3c41cffd76dad"
      }
    ],
    "tls_version_record": "771",
    "tls_version_negotiated": "772",
    "ja3": "771,4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53,65281-35-0-18-13-16-23-43-27-51-17513-45-10-11-5-21-41,29-23-24,0",
    "ja3_hash": "c238fc8220c1fc1aa01cd2e11a95415f",
    "peetprint": "GREASE-772-771|2-1.1|GREASE-29-23-24|1027-2052-1025-1283-2053-1281-2054-1537|1|2|GREASE-4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53|0-10-11-13-16-17513-18-21-23-27-35-41-43-45-5-51-65281-GREASE-GREASE",
    "peetprint_hash": "a0468212376b470d0ee57e6922986be3",
    "client_random": "ed96a8a53f8237a55a696a045488ffab3f6ad03dc6b741bc21ceff34aa3d5962",
    "session_id": "abee7435a568f83998b53534445c8e2e659635a158df3d94c530b5e070958f3b"
  },
  "http2": {
    "akamai_fingerprint": "1:65536,2:0,3:1000,4:6291456,6:262144|15663105|0|m,a,s,p",
    "akamai_fingerprint_hash": "46cedabdca2073198a42fa10ca4494d0",
    "sent_frames": [
      {
        "frame_type": "SETTINGS",
        "length": 30,
        "settings": [
          "HEADER_TABLE_SIZE = 65536",
          "ENABLE_PUSH = 0",
          "MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS = 1000",
          "INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE = 6291456",
          "MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE = 262144"
        ]
      },
      {
        "frame_type": "WINDOW_UPDATE",
        "length": 4,
        "increment": 15663105
      },
      {
        "frame_type": "HEADERS",
        "stream_id": 1,
        "length": 439,
        "headers": [
          ":method: GET",
          ":authority: tls.peet.ws",
          ":scheme: https",
          ":path: /api/all",
          "cache-control: max-age=0",
          "sec-ch-ua: \\\"Not.A/Brand\\\";v=\\\"8\\\", \\\"Chromium\\\";v=\\\"114\\\", \\\"Google Chrome\\\";v=\\\"114\\",
          "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0",
          "sec-ch-ua-platform: \\\"Windows\\",
          "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1",
          "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
          "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
          "sec-fetch-site: none",
          "sec-fetch-mode: navigate",
          "sec-fetch-user: ?1",
          "sec-fetch-dest: document",
          "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
          "accept-language: en"
        ],
        "flags": [
          "EndStream (0x1)",
          "EndHeaders (0x4)",
          "Priority (0x20)"
        ],
        "priority": {
          "weight": 256,
          "depends_on": 0,
          "exclusive": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: I added the screenshots

Comment: Please don't post text as screenshots.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Which differences in the results are you interested in?

Comment: tls - > ciphers

Comment: `HttpClient` supports a different set of ciphers than the browser you're using.

Comment: Yes, so I tried in several ways. How to resolve it?
I want to make java response the same as browser response

Comment: How did you 'try' to affect the cipher selection?

Comment: ```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
SSLParameters sslParameters = sslContext.getDefaultSSLParameters();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .sslParameters(sslParameters)
                .build();
```

Comment: That's not what the code in your question says.

Comment: How to make the same? Can you help me?

Comment: Your Java code uses the Java implementation of TLS (JSSE). Your browser uses a different implementation of TLS, depending on which browser it is. Different implementations are different (even if you set _some applevel_ headers to lie about what you are using, as you did).

Comment: Can you explain why you want these to be the same? I can't imagine a situation where it matters.

Comment: @tgdavies could you please check this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618680/support-tls-grease-in-java